# Return statements in java with integers

Tags: java, methods, static, integer, return

I am having trouble grasping four different return statement problems in java which deal with integers. They usually go by the names of "mystery" and "enigma". I have tried solving them numerous times, and the web and my text book do not contain any similar examples for me to work with. My gut feeling is I am missing something with the logic. If someone can maybe just explain on of the problems (preferably the hardest one), I am sure I will understand it. I apoligise in advance if the format is not on par with this site's requirements, since it is my first time posting.

```
 1   public class Program 1{
 2
 3   public static int y = 2;
 4
 5   public static int mystery(int x, int y) {
 6      y = y + x;
 7      return x + y;
 8   }
 9
10   public static void main(String[] args) {
11      int x = 1;
12      x = mystery(x, y);
13      y = mystery(y, x);
14      System.out.println(x + " " + y);
15   }
16}
17 // Answer : 4 8
 I get x to be 4, but I struggle to get y to be 8.


1 public class Program 2{
 2
 3   public static int y = 2;
 4
 5   public static int mystery(int a, int b) {
 6      y = b + a;
 7      return a + b;
 8   }
 9
10   public static void main(String[] args) {
11      int x = 1;
12      x = mystery(x, y);
13      y = mystery(y, x);
14      System.out.println(x + " " + y);
15   }
16}
17 // Answer : 3 6
 I get x to be 3, but I struggle to get y to be 6.


1 public class Program 3{
 2
 3   public static int x = 1;
 4   public static int y = 2;
 5
 6   public static int mystery1(int a, int b) {
 7      x = a + b;
 8      return b + a;
 9   }
10
11   public static int mystery2(int a, int b) {
12      y = b + a;
13      x = mystery1(a, b);
14      return a + b;
15   }
16
17   public static void main(String[] args) {
18      x = mystery2(x, y);
19      System.out.println(x + " " + y);
20   }
21
22}
23 // Answer : 3 3
 I get x to be 3, but I struggle to get y to be 3.



public class Enigma {

public static int x = 1;
public static int y = 2;
public static int n = 0;

public static int aaa(int a, int b) {
n++; 
return a + b;
}

public static int bbb(int a, int b) {
n++; x = aaa(x, a); y = aaa(y, b); 
return x + y;
}

public static void ccc(int x, int q) {
n++; x = bbb(1, x); y = bbb(2, q);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
int x = aaa(3, y); 
y = bbb(x, y); ccc(x, 1);
System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + n);
// Answer : 5 25 11
I get x to be 5, but I struggle to get y = 25 and n = 11, although incrementing n at each method is probably the reason why.
```

Comment: You're shadowing your class variable `y` with a parameter also called `y` in your `mystery` method in program 1.

Comment: Class name should be one word (not two as currently)

Comment: Yes I know, I spaced it before posting for easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make things less confusing by not keep using the same variables. For example, in main program, create new variables (lets say a and b) and instead write "int a=mystery(x,y);" and "int b=mystery(y,x);" for program 1.

1) Lets first solve the problem you have in Program 1. First the program runs code line 12, which is x=mystery(x,y), and x is 1, y=2.
2) So x=mystery(1,2). When you run that, you assign y=y+x, y is still 2, and x is still 1, 2+1=3, therefore now y is 3 and x is still 1. 
3) Then you tell the program to return y+x, or 3+1, and you assign it to x. Now x=4 and y is 3.
4)Your program runs line 13, with y=3 and **x=4**, therefore y=(3,4). So y=y+x is y=3+4, or 7. 
5) THIS IS WHEN YOU MESSED UP! you expected x to still be 1, but it isn't anymore, it is 4, and therefore you get 11.

Please leave a comment if you don't understand. If possible, please tell me where you get stuck by using the numbering I provided :) Good luck

Comment: I see what you mean! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Program1:

x = mystery(x, y) -> returning 4 , so x=4, your class y stays 2(if you want to access class y, use 'this' keyword.

y = mystery(y, x) -> mystery(2,4) returning 2+6=8

Program2:

x = mystery(x, y) -> class y is now 3, returning 3, x=3

y = mystery(y, x) -> mystery(3,3) returning 6

Program3:

x = mystery2(x, y) -> class y is now 3, mystery1(1, 2) -> returning 3, so class x=3

Enigma:

int x = aaa(3, y) -> returning 5, n=1

y = bbb(x, y) -> n=4, x=6, y=4, returns 10. So class y=10

In method ccc, n becomes 11 (1+3+3).
Note that in method ccc you're shadowing the class member x. instead it is the local one from the parameter.